# How to take screen shot for an exception in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created a function for screen shot and it is working but I want to take screen shot for any exception and below is the code:

> c#

```
public static void SnapSreenshot()
{
    PalV3.wait(20);
    path = @"E:\Accounts\Screenshot\";
    string timeanddate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_mm_yyy hh.mm.ss");
    DirectoryInfo DirectPath = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    if(DirectPath.Exists)
    {
        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)BasePage.cd).GetScreenshot();
        ss.SaveAsFile(path+timeanddate.ToString(), ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    else
    {
        DirectPath.Create();
        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)BasePage.cd).GetScreenshot();
        ss.SaveAsFile(path + timeanddate.ToString(), ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you want to achieve? You want ti take screenshot after each exception of the tested or in the testing code?

Comment: The question is not totally clear, are you saying you want to take a screenshot on test failure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i want to take screenshot after the execution of a test case and also if any exception occurs.

Comment: Which version you are using 2 0r 3?

Comment: @Navarasu Sir, I am using version 3, and i have a doubt the  below code is not  working under Teardown attribute but working under Testcleanup attribute why is that sir??

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to take a screenshot on test failure then you want to hook into some sort of after scenario or tear down block.

Using specflow/selenium there is an AfterScenario() method which can be used. You could write something like -

```
[AfterScenario()]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            SnapSreenshot();
        }
    }
```

Obviously if you are using other test frameworks you may need to use different method names, however I imagine the general principle is the same.

Comment: Sir , i am using Unit framework without specflows and i want to take screenshot after the execution of a test case and also if any exception occurs

Comment: Check the documentation for your framework, or ask someone who has used it before. There is likely to be some sort of after test hook available to you.

Comment: This is the right way to do this... or some variation of this. Why would you want to take a screenshot at the end of a successful run?